# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\cos(kt)}{k}f(s)\cos(ks)ds$ is a compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, compact-operators

> Consider $X=L[0,\pi]$ and define
> $$T(f)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\cos(kt)}{k}f(s)\cos(ks)ds.$$
> Show that $T$ is a compact operator and find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

First I define $T_n(f)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\cos(kt)}{k}f(s)\cos(ks)ds$ but does $T_n \rightarrow T$ in the operator norm? I am not sure about this. Is this the right way?
I will be very grateful for any hint or suggestion.

Comment: Are you sure this is a bounded operator on $L[0,\pi]$?

Comment: If $X=L^{2}[0,\pi]$ then $T$ is a well defined bounded operator and it is also compact. Perhaps, there is a typo in the question.

Comment: The operator is of the form $$Tf=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \langle f,v_k\rangle v_k$$ where $v_k=\sqrt{2\pi^{-1}}\cos kx,$ $a_k=2^{-1}\pi k^{-1}.$  The functions $v_k$ form an orthonormal set in $L^2(0,\pi).$ Such operator is compact when $a_k\to 0.$ Its eigenvalues are $a_k$ and the corresponding eigenfunctions are $v_k.$